# Google App Script : "range.isBlank()" is false but "if(range.isBlank())" go through?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, boolean

I'm using Google App Script. It's based on Javascript.
I use a function `range.isBlank()` which respond with a false boolean.
I checked in debug it's a false Boolean.

But with great surprise I discover statement `if(range.isBlank()) {...}`
go through the code...

I tried some solution found in the site including using `===true`.
But nothing works.

To reproduce, create a spreadsheet and in the active sheet put some data like that :

```
   |       A         |   B   |   C   |   D   |  E   |
1     "Larry Page"       1       2       3
2     "Larry Page"       1       2
3     "Larry Page"       1
```

In the script editor copy the code below and execute the function.

```
function DebugGoogle() {

    var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ssheet.getActiveSheet()

// Get sheet dimension   
    var nbRow = sheet.getMaxRows();

// Loop on the rows
    for (var i=1; i<=nbRow; i++) {

// Start at the first column
        var range = sheet.getRange(i, 1);
        var nextRange = sheet.getRange(i, range.getLastColumn()+1);
        if (nextRange.isBlank()); {
            nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank());
        }

// Go right As long as the next right cell is not empty
        while (!(nextRange.isBlank())) {
            range = nextRange;
            nextRange = sheet.getRange(i, range.getLastColumn()+1);
            if (nextRange.isBlank()); {
                nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect a note only on the first empty cell of each line.
D for line 1, C for line 2, B for line 3.
Instead of that I also have note for non-empty cells.
Which is odd because the note is "false" but the if statement enter ...

```
if (nextRange.isBlank()); {
    nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank());
}
```

I was expected only note with true value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is correctly copied from your current script, I think that in your script, the issue is `;` of `if (nextRange.isBlank()); {`. In this case, `nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank())` is always run. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (nextRange.isBlank()); {
    nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank());
}
```

#### To:

```
if (nextRange.isBlank()) {  // Modified
    nextRange.setNote(nextRange.isBlank());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right. It works now.... Many Thanks ! (and sorry for this obvious mistake)

Comment: @Bleuzaille No problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.